# Cannot run specific Firefox profile in Selenium using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to run Selenium in an existing Firefox profile using Node.js. However, Node keeps saying that it can't find the profile. I'm running Arch Linux and Firefox 87. My code:

```
const webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");
const firefox = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox");
const geckodriver = require("geckodriver"); //Did this instead of adding geckodriver to Path
const firefoxOptions = new firefox.Options();
const firefoxProfile = '/home/user_name/.mozilla/firefox/l6mcped3.selenium-test/';
firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser("firefox")
    .setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions)
    .build();
```

The result (running with the Firefox profile closed):

```
Running...
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user_name/.mozilla/firefox/l6mcped3.selenium-test/lock'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/user_name/.mozilla/firefox/l6mcped3.selenium-test/lock'
```

However, `ls` shows the file exists. User permission shouldn't be an issue, but I tried running as `sudo` anyway and got the same result. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try *deleting* the symlink. That has worked for me. ‍♂️